# Pass value from one workflow to another which are not dependant on each other- Github actions Azure Static Web apps

Tags: github-actions, azure-static-web-app

I am building my app using Github actions and deploying using Azure Static Web apps. When I open a new pull request, a workflow runs which gets the deployment url and adds it to my list of redirect urls in my Azure App registration. However, when I close the pull request, I want to get the same url and go ahead and remove the value from app registration. I am having some trouble passing values from the open workflow to the close workflow since they are not happening together. When I close the pull request, only the closepullrequest job is called. Please advice.

This is my yml:

```
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - dev
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]
    branches:
      - dev

jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy Job
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          submodules: true
      - name: Get yarn cache directory path
        id: yarn-cache-dir-path
        run: echo "::set-output name=dir::$(yarn config get cacheFolder)"

      - uses: actions/cache@v2
        id: yarn-cache # use this to check for `cache-hit` (`steps.yarn-cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'`)
        with:
          path: ${{ steps.yarn-cache-dir-path.outputs.dir }}
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-${{ hashFiles('**/yarn.lock') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-

      - name: Build And Deploy
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_HAPPY_RIVER_01F5A930F }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} # Used for Github integrations (i.e. PR comments)
          action: "upload"
          ###### Repository/Build Configurations - These values can be configured to match your app requirements. ######
          # For more information regarding Static Web App workflow configurations, please visit: https://aka.ms/swaworkflowconfig
          app_location: "/" # App source code path
          api_location: "" # Api source code path - optional
          output_location: "build" # Built app content directory - optional
        env:
          VITE_AG_GRID_LICENSE_KEY: ${{secrets.VITE_AG_GRID_LICENSE_KEY}}
          VITE_API_SCOPE: ${{secrets.VITE_API_SCOPE}}
          VITE_CLIENT_ID: ${{secrets.VITE_CLIENT_ID}}
          VITE_SOURCE_LOADER_BASE_URL: ${{secrets.VITE_SOURCE_LOADER_BASE_URL_DEV}}
          VITE_TENANT_ID: ${{secrets.VITE_TENANT_ID}}
      - run: echo ${{ steps.builddeploy.outputs.static_web_app_url }}

      - name: Add redirect uri
        id: addRedirectUri
        uses: fjogeleit/http-request-action@master
        with:
          url: 'url'
          method: 'POST'
          data: '{"redirectURI": "${{steps.builddeploy.outputs.static_web_app_url}}", "route": "create"}'

  close_pull_request_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Close Pull Request Job
    steps:
      - name: Close Pull Request
        id: closepullrequest
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_HAPPY_RIVER_01F5A930F }}
          action: "close"
      - run: echo ${{ steps.closepullrequest.outputs.static_web_app_url }}
      - name: Remove redirect uri
        id: removeRedirectUri
        uses: fjogeleit/http-request-action@master
        with:
          url: 'url'
          method: 'POST'
          data: '{"redirectURI": "${{ steps.closepullrequest.outputs.static_web_app_url }}", "route": "delete"}'
```

Comment: You could use PR comment to save deployment URL on your open PR workflow, then on close PR you just check PR comments for URL.